# tyring to test for exception using python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

I have the following code:

```
class cutomTests(unittest.TestCase, moduleName.className):

    def test_input_too_large(self):
      '''className.functionName should fail with large input'''
      self.assertRaises(moduleName.OutOfRangeError, self.functionName(4000)
```

I got the following result:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_input_too_large (__main__.customTests)
className.functionName should fail with large input
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/workspace//ClassNameTests.py", line 37, in test_input_too_large
  self.assertRaises(toRoman.OutOfRangeError, self.answer(4000))
  File "/home/user/workspace/moduleName.py", line 47, in answer
  raise OutOfRangeError()
OutOfRangeError
```

So the results should be pass right because the exception is raised???

Answer (score 2):

You need to let `assertRaises` call the function rather than doing it yourself:

```
self.assertRaises(OutOfRangeError, self.functionName, 4000)
```

Right now, you're *calling* `self.functionName` and passing its *result* to `assertRaises`.  Obviously, if `self.functionName` raises and exception, it won't get caught by `assertRaises` because `assertRaises` won't have been called yet at that point :-).

Note that as of python2.7, `assertRaises` can be used as a context manager which is a lot more convenient:

```
with self.assertRaises(OutOfRangeError):
    self.functionName(4000)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You should use `assertRaises` method as context manager.

```
with self.assertRaises(moduleName.OutOfRangeError):
    self.functionName(4000)
```

Another usage is to pass function and arguments as next arguments. However it's not that pretty:

```
self.assertRaises(moduleName.OutOfRangeError, self.functionName, 4000)
```

Comment: what is the difference between the two and what does context manager do